# SwiftのPDFKitで画像が上下に反転してしまいます

Tags: swift

swift4.0にてPDFKitを使ってPDF作成を試みています。
PDF自体は簡単に作成できたのですが、中身を開くと上下に反転した画像になっていました。
何かの指定が足りない／余分なのかもしれません。ご教授願います。

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // PDF化し、URLを返す
    func createPDF()->URL {
        let document :PDFDocument = PDFDocument()
        let page1 : PDFPage = PDFPage(image: UIImage(named: "IMG_0115.jpg")!)!
        document.insert(page1, at: document.pageCount)
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true).first!

        let url:URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath+"/output.pdf")
        document.write(to: url)
        return url
    }

    @IBAction func pdfAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let url:URL = createPDF()
        let items = [url]
        let activityVc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities:nil)
        self.present(activityVc, animated: true, completion: nil)        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PDFKitのバグではないかと思います。
現状、UIImageを反転させてからPDFPageを生成するしか、回避方法がありません。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46219729/pdfkit-is-vertically-flipping-pdfpage-initialised-with-image